# Visual Studio 2008 - Focus on textbox doesn't work when run from VS2008 as admin

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, vista64

This is a minor, esoteric problem and not a showstopper, but I'm wondering what other VS2008 idiosyncrasies are out there.

If you make a web app, add a textbox and run a focus function for the textbox on page load, it works when you run VS *not* as administrator from a Vista non-administrator account or if you run the page from a browser instance run on its own, not from VS.

If you browse the page from VS as Admin, the focus doesn't work.  This for Cassini and from the local IIS.

Stuff like this just makes me trust VS a tad less.

Comment: Small comment.  This almost certainly has nothing to do with VS because it's actually happening in your application.  It probably has much more to do with running various programs with different sets of credentials.

Comment: Yes, the Vista security threw me off, running applications as admin or as a non-admin just complicates things.  I found the problem, as my ie security was set differently for the admin account, as I was testing with Javascript disabled and enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, this was my own bloody fault.  I found the problem, as my ie security was set differently for the admin account which had Javascript disabled.